# Magento 2 Programatically update price attribututes per store but code is updating for all stores

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price

I want to update price for particular store(us) by programmatically.I used below script and its working but problem is it updates for all stores not for particular

```
function updateconfigProductPrice($productsku_update,$price_to_update,$storeCode)
             {
                $proObj = getObjectInstance()->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
                if ($proObj->getIdBySku($productsku_update))
                {
                   $productId = $proObj->getIdBySku($productsku_update);
                }
                else
                {
                   return FALSE;
                }


                if($storeCode=='us')
                {
                  $storeId = '9';
                }


                //echo 'store_code'.$storeId;   

               if ($productId!= '') {
                    $configProduct = getObjectInstance()->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);

                    //var_dump($configProduct->getWebsiteIds());
                    //die;
                    $_children = $configProduct->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts($configProduct);
                    //echo count($_children);die;

                    foreach ($_children as $child) {


                        //echo $child->getSku();die;

                        if($child->getID()!=''){

                            $childId = $child->getID();

                        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                        $productFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
                        $productResourceModel = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product');
                        $productResourceModel->load($productFactory, $childId);
                        $productFactory->setStoreId($storeId);

                        $special_price = $price_to_update;
                        $productFactory->setPrice($special_price);
                        $productResourceModel->saveAttribute($productFactory, 'price');
                        echo $child->getSku()."child product updated for store==".$storeId."=with s Price".$special_price.".<br/>";
                        }
                    }

                }
             }
```

Its update price for all stores but I want to update only for my US(store). Please share your thoughts and let me know what is wrong with code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if price update then just only one change below way then you can try it

Go to **System->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog Price Scope**

Then in the tab **Price**, set price scope to **Website** instead of global.

**note**:

If applied at the *global level*, the same price is used throughout the store hierarchy. If the price configuration is set to the *website level*, the same product can be available at different prices in different stores.

Comment: Will it work without effecting to other stores?

Comment: yes working not effecting another store

Comment: Ok thanks,I am trying.why this option is not enabled default?

Comment: i have updated note in my answer

Comment: I created custom API to update details but I want to update detail based on store code and store code is collected from payload any idea?

Comment: Hi @RakeshDonga. I have 2 stores English and Chinese and set Price to Website, now If i'm changing price for a store then it is automatically changing for the another store too while all store view has unchanged price

Answer (score 1):

Along with the above suggestion by Rakesh - which will fix your main issue - for the actual update it would be more efficient to use the product action class:

`\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action`

`$productIds = [1];
$data = ['price'=>12.00, 'special_price'=>10.00];
$storeId = 1;`

`$productAction->updateAttributes($productids, $data, $storeId);`

This will save the attribute (such as price, special price, or anything else) without saving the product itself and is a lot quicker - even if you go one by one specifying the product ids.

Answer (score 0):

Using update attribute works, but i cannot figure out why magento does not allow us to update price using save() on price model or productRepository.